# Pass initial value using script but keep interacting in terminal with a program

Tags: bash, shell

Here's my interactive program:

```py
import sys

print ("what's your name?")

sys.stdout.write("> ")
sys.stdout.flush()

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip()

    if line == "q":
        break

    print ("hello", line)

    sys.stdout.write("> ")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

it runs in a loop:

```
$ python3 name.py
what's your name?
> tom
hello tom
> john
hello john
```

what I want is to initially pass input, `name` in this case, but to be able to further interact with the program.

what I have so far is this:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

echo "mr. big" | python3 name.py
```

however this runs the program and immediately exits:

```
$ ./script
what's your name?
> hello mr. big
> $
```

Comment: It exits, because it runs on EOF in stdin. Without modifying `name.py` itself, I suggest that you use [expect](https://www2.lib.uchicago.edu/keith/tcl-course/topics/expect.html)  for this task. `expect` has a command `interact`, which hands over control to interactive use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?
[image]

```
#!/bin/bash

(echo "mr. big"; cat) | python3 test.py
```

In your script the `echo "mr. big" | python3 name.py`, the input is piped directly from the echo command to your python script. This means that the `echo` closes the input after the first value you provided and it terminates your script.

And here using `(echo "mr. big"; cat) | python3 name.py` subshell that first echoes the initial value "mr. big" and then uses `cat` to read more user inputs from your program basically. Essentially you are piping the output of the subshell to your Python script which keeps the input open for continued interaction.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I wanted. Can you also add an explanation why this works?

Comment: Np, updated the code @d9ngle